# Github gist height is fixed in Medium blog. Why?

Tags: github, gist, medium.com-publishing-api

I'm trying to include a Github gist code in a Medium blog. But when I try to include the code in blog it takes a fixed height even though there are only 2 lines in the gist code.
Also are there any other public gist creator which I can use to include gist code in the Medium blog.

Here's what's happening when there are only few lines of code...
[image]

And then when I add scrollable code this happens...
[image]

The rest of the code is cut from bottom.

Comment: If it's only two lines of code, why not create simply code block ?

Comment: @DinkoPehar what do u mean by that ?

Comment: Please refer to this article for explanation https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-add-code-to-medium-and-get-syntax-highlighting-d699761a5883

Comment: @DinkoPehar no i dont want to use code blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. This issue should now be resolved and working as expected. Please let us know if you find other issues by submitting a support ticket at yourfriends.medium.com.

Thanks!

Luke from Medium